# Storing the result of "find" in a variable?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to get the number of files in a directory tree.

The command `find . -type f` lists the files each on new line when I run it but if I store the result of the command in a variable, it stores it all on one line when I then echo that variable.
So if I then want to count the number of files via a for cycle, I stumble across a problem with files that have blank spaces in their name.

So is there a way to store the output of the find command in a variable where each file name is on new line? That way by counting the number of lines, I will get the number of files.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to put double quotes around the variable when you use it.

Comment: Why not directly use something like `find . -type f | wc -l` to get the number of files?

Comment: Oh you're right, that will be the best way! I already used this command but completely forgot about it, thanks a lot! : )

Comment: @Daeto The accepted answer is a better solution, but the direct one is described here: [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `wc` with `-l` option to count line in a file. For you case :

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

should work.

Comment: Doesn't work with files with newlines in the name. Also requires running `find` twice if you want to do anything with the found files (which then introduces a race condition where files may be added or removed between the calls to `find`). But without knowing what the OPs **actual** goal here is improving this answer can only be taken so far.

Comment: "with newlines in the name", does it really exist ? :)

Comment: Often? No. Occasionally? Yes. Better to prepare for it then to be bitten by it? Also yes.